# "How to create two text widgets in a row widget"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

"I'm a beginner in flutter, I want to display two text in row .where "hello" is the first text widget and "world" is another text widget

I tried doing this with my basic knowledge but I came across these errors

> Horizontal RenderFlex with multiple children has a null textDirection, so the layout order is undefined.
>   'package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart':
>   Failed assertion: line 439 pos 18: 'textDirection != null'

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("hello",textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,),
        Text("world",textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you want to use RichText instead?

```dart
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'hello', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read this link about Row in Flutter:

```
https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-row-column-cheat-sheet-78c38d242041
```

In a nutshell, you Declare a Row and the items that will be inside that row are the children (Which must be widgets).

I picked an example from here
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout

something like this

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [
    Image.asset('images/pic1.jpg'),
    Image.asset('images/pic2.jpg'),
    Image.asset('images/pic3.jpg'),
  ],
);
```

In Your case, you just have to erase the image.asset and change it for texts...

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [
    Text('Hello'),
    Text('World'),

  ],
);
```

or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:-

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("Hello",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
        Text("World",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))
      ],
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try This Simplest Way**

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
        Text("Hello"),
        Text("World"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the 'Row' into 'Column' and it worked

```
child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: const [
              Text(
                'Good Morning!',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 30),
              ),
              Text('scott'),
              GradientContainer(),
              textMy(),
            ],
          ),
```